# What does this strange complicated sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

**Blue rolled the sky...**

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Without context this is unanswerable. *With* context, it would probably be Off Topic Lit Crit.

Comment: My guess is that it's a typo for, or a misreading of, _roiled_.

Answer (score 2):

The sky was blue and the author had caught a nasty dose of inappropriately applied poetry

Answer (score 1):

> Green grows the laurel
>  Soft falls the dew
>  Sorry was I
>  When I parted
>   from you
>   [English folksong]

It's a poetic way of saying *The sky rolled blue*, with a dubious use of 'rolled'